# autofill list column from Person Group fields

Tags: 2013, custom-list, person

In a SharePoint 2013 custom list I have a Person/Group column `Staff_Name` that lets me pull staff name from Active Directory. There are other text columns in the same list that I want auto fill with the same staff related info, like Email, Office, Department etc.

How can this be achieved. I can do it through SP designer if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Two options

1. Using an `EventReceiver` capture `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` events. Then get the additional information and save it to the required fields
2. Using JavaScript Object Model and jQuery, capture the change event of the picker control and get additional details. Populate the text fields. On save this goes to the list.

Option 1 is easier to implement, but has a bad user experience because user is not aware of the extra information that get saved

Option 2 is difficult to implement but has a better user experience.